# Trocar Valores de String de um Dataset para valores 'Float'

Tags: python, dataset

Boa tarde pessoal!!! Estou com um probleminha para realizar um trabalho de uma matéria da faculdade. Estou pegando o um dataset pronto de um outro artigo que foi realizado.

O Dataset é mais ou menos assim:

```
3,24.3,389693,21,23,tcp,1540,-------,4,11339,16091,24780100,Switch1,Router,35.529786,35.529786,35.539909,0,328.240918,505490,1540,0.236321,0,35.519662,35.550032,1,50.02192,Normal
15,24.15,201196,23,24,tcp,1540,-------,16,6274,16092,24781700,Router,server1,20.176725,20.176725,20.186848,0,328.205808,505437,1540,0.236337,0,20.156478,20.186848,1,50.030211,Normal
24.15,15,61905,23,22,ack,55,-------,16,1930,16092,885060,Router,Switch2,7.049955,7.049955,7.059958,0,328.206042,18051.3,55,0.008441,0,7.039952,7.069962,1.030045,50.060221,UDP-Flood
24.9,9,443135,23,21,ack,55,-------,10,12670,16085,884675,Router,Switch1,39.62797,39.62797,39.637973,0,328.064183,18043.5,55,0.008437,0,39.617967,39.647976,1.030058,50.060098,Normal
24.8,8,157335,23,21,ack,55,-------,9,4901,16088,884840,Router,Switch1,16.039806,16.039806,16.04981,0,328.113525,18046.2,55,0.008438,0,16.029803,16.059813,1.030054,50.061864,Normal
24.1,1,219350,21,1,ack,55,-------,2,6837,16091,885005,Switch1,clien-1,21.885768,21.885768,21.895771,0,328.297902,18056.4,55,0.00844,0,21.865762,21.895771,1.030016,50.043427,Normal
24.13,13,480053,24,23,ack,55,-------,14,13609,16103,885665,server1,Router,42.45032,42.45032,42.460323,0,328.460278,18065.3,55,0.008446,0,42.45032,42.48033,1.030032,50.055747,Normal
```

É um dataset que disponibilizaram a respeito de ataques de DDoS. Irei a partir desse dataset realizar a aplicação de classificadores supervisionados como o NaiveBayes, RandomForest e Multi Layer Perceptron (Inteligencia Artificial).

A linguagem que estou utilizando é Python (Obrigatorio) e estou usando o Numpy para pegar o dataset. Essa função esta assim:

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: "{0:0.10f}".format(x)}) 
X = np.loadtxt("datasetTrabalho.data", delimiter=",")
```

Porém toda a vez que tento fazer qualquer coisa dá erros como esse:

```
File "trabalho.py", line 190, in <module>
    main()
  File "trabalho.py", line 98, in main
    X = np.loadtxt("testeTrabalho.data", delimiter=",") # pega o dataset
  File "/home/arthur/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1101, in loadtxt
    for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
  File "/home/arthur/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1028, in read_data
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "/home/arthur/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1028, in <listcomp>
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "/home/arthur/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 746, in floatconv
    return float(x)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'tcp'
```

Preciso de uma ajuda de meios para trocar esses valores Strings do Dataset para valores Inteiros, para assim usar os devidos classificadores para o trabalho. Interessante se alguém também tiver uma outra biblioteca para solucionar esse problema. Estarei grato pela a ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para converter o tipo dos dados em uma coluna do DataFrame (se estiver utilizando o Pandas), você pode executar o comando:

```
DF['NomeDaColuna'] = DF['NomeDaColuna'].astype(float)   # converte para float, neste caso
```

Como você estará convertendo *strings* em *floats*, certifique-se que as *strings* possuem o formato 'x.y', onde x e y são números (também funciona sem a parte decimal '.y')

Comment: Resolveu, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @ArthurAbitante que bom!! :)

Answer (score 0):

E o erro é que o numpy tá tentando converter números para float como você definiu mas há uma string "tcp" na primeira linha, com isso causando a exceção.

**ALTERNATIVA**

Você poderia utilizar a biblioteca [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), onde é uma lib de tratamento de dados.

Com ela você leria esse dataset tranquilamente. Sugiro utilizar junto com o [jupyter](http://jupyter.org/).